# Form design from dll project other than from winforms project

Tags: c#, winforms, dll

So when I create and do what ever I like to do with a winforms project on my Win10 PC, all the forms in that project have that kind of Metro Style UI design.
However if I create a dll project on the same PC, and reference to what I think is the same System.Windows.Forms dll as the winforms projects do, the forms I can create from the dll look a little bit as if I was on Win7 and had enabled the use XpVisualStyles option.
i.e.: As an basic example: all buttons on the form are set to a 3d border style by default and trying to get them to be flat is not that easy (if they should look good atleast)

Question is: Why do the forms created from the dll look differend than the ones created from a winforms application, althought they both reference the same dll (System.Windows.Forms I even checked hash and version)?
2nd Part how can I get the forms created from the dll to look like the ones from an winforms project?

Additional Information: The dll forms have been created by referencing the dll from 1 a console project and 2 an other winforms project. Both looked like Xp.

Comment: Look in the main entry point of the program, `Main` method, usually in `Program.cs` and see if there is `Application.EnableVisualStyles();` before `Application.Run(new SomeForm());`. It enables visual styles in your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to the nice comment by @Reza Aghaei this question is solved.

---

### 1st Solution

Make sure that in the Application that opens the form the `Appliction.EnableVisualStyles();` is called, this requires a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` if there is none.
The shown form will then look just like it shows you in the designer that it will.

### 2nd Solution

Call the `Appliction.EnableVisualStyles();` inside the dll that owns the form.
This be done by

- Calling in the constructor of each form
- Or via some static function in the dll that takes care of all initialization

additionally there could be a conditional inside the form constructor that calls some function of the same dll that checks if styles are enabled and if not does so.

I would based on my knowledge commend to use a static initialization function.